# Tikz: flow chart how to write label over a line

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, write

I'm using TikZ to design a flowchart. In this flowchart I have two types of boxes:

- a normal rectangle
- a diamond box (as a decision)

For the decision box, I need to write on top of the line that connects the diamond to the box below, the result of the choice: "YES" or "NO".

I post one flow, so you can see how as I built the flow.

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains} 
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} %----permette il posizionamento relativo dei nodi
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %----permette l' uso dei caratteri accentati
\usepackage[italian]{babel} %-----permette la sillabazione secondo le regole italiane
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}%    
\begin{document}https://preview.overleaf.com/public/xntbjwvtpkxb/images/4bb96421dbe314bc6c6e75376a3e10fc25eee129.jpeg 
% =================================================
% Set up a few colours questi sono i colori poi usati per le linee i connettori e il riempimento di alcune forme, variando il numero del colore, varia il coloreetc. tipo: riga di colore lcfree
\colorlet{lcfree}{Green3} 
\colorlet{lcnorm}{Blue3}
\colorlet{lccong}{Red3}

\providecommand{\cmark}[2][]{\relax} %------crea il comando \cmark utilizzato in seguito
% ----------------QUESTO PEZZO INDICA COME FARE LA CATENA ---!!!!!!!---
% Start the picture
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    >=triangle 60,              % Nice arrows;variando i simboli > e =, cambia la forma della freccia
    start chain=going below,    % General flow is top-to-bottom unisce i blocchi andando da sopra a sotto
    node distance=16mm and 60mm, % Global setup of box spacing 16mm verticale 60 orizzontale
    every join/.style={norm},   % Default linetype for connecting boxes utilizzando lo stile norm/free/cong definiti a riga 87
    ]
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
%in questa area vengono definiti gli stili delle forme da inserire nelle griglie.Questi stili vengono poi usati per dare forma ai vari nodi, usando il nome dello stile come primo parametro del nodo. es. \node [proc, join...]
% A few box styles 
% <on chain> *and* <on grid> reduce the need for manual relative
% positioning of nodes
\tikzset{
%--il parametro align= allinea il testo all interno della forma (left, center, right)
    base/.style={draw, on chain, on grid, align=center, minimum height=4ex},
    proc/.style={base, rectangle, text width=8em},
    test/.style={base, diamond, aspect=2, text width=5em},
    term/.style={proc, rounded corners},
% coord node style is used for placing corners of connecting lines
  coord/.style={coordinate, on chain, on grid, node distance=6mm and 25mm},
% nmark node style is used for coordinate debugging marks
  nmark/.style={draw, cyan, circle, font={\sffamily\bfseries}},
%======================fine definizione stili delle forme
% Connector line styles for different parts of the diagram. qui si definiscono gli stili dei connettori. Il colore del connettore (lcnorm, lcfree, lccong) sono a loro volta definiti ella sezione (set up a few color alcune righe sopra)
  norm/.style={->, draw, lcnorm},
  free/.style={->, draw, lcfree},
  cong/.style={->, draw, lccong},
  it/.style={font={\small\itshape}} %questo DOVREBBE configurafre un font
}
% ----------------------------------inizio posizionamento forme--------
% Start by placing the nodes il parametro join serve a collegare il nodo con il precedente. per i collegamenti specifici (tipo nodo sssc0003 a nodo sssc0004, vedere il codice che inizia con: "All the other connections... alle righe succesive
%------*********inizio posizionamento delle forme I colonna******--------------------
% Use join to connect a node to the previous one ------uso di join per connettere i nodi ai blocchi precedenti--------------
\node [proc, densely dotted, it] (sspO0001) {Presentazione domanda};
\node [test, join] (sspo0002) {Domanda formalmente completa?};
\node [proc, join] (sspo0011) {Comunicazione avvio procedimento e convocazione CdS (endo > 90 gg.)};
\node [proc, join] (sspo0013) {trasmissione verbale conferenza o provvedimento finale};

\node [term, join] (sspo0099)    {chiusura procedimento};
%-----------------------------fine I colonna---------------
%---------------inizio II  e III colonna------------------------------
\node [proc ] (ssri-cap) [left=of sspO0001] {Comunicazione apertura pratica al reg imprese};
\node [proc, join] (ssri-cep) [left=of ssri-cap]  {comunicazione esito pratica al registro delle imrese};

%-----seconda colonna----------------------------
\node [proc, ] (sspo0003)[left=of sspo0011] {Comunicazione avvio procedimento e trasmissione richiesta pareri / atti};
\node [test, join] (sspo0004) {istanza necessita di integrazione da parte di utenti terzi?};
\node [proc, join] (sspo0005) {richiesta documentaz. integrativa (interruzione)};
\node [proc, join] (sspo0006) {ricezione documentazione integrativa};
\node [proc, join] (sspo0007) {trasmissione integrazione alle P.A.};
\node [test, join] (sspo0008) {ricezione pareri/atti nei termini?};
\node [test, join] (sspo0009) {parere positivo endoprocedimento?};
Presentazione osservazioni (10gg)
\node [proc, join] (sspo0010) {rilascio e trasmissione provvedimento};
\node [proc, join] (sssc9999) {chiusura procedimento};
\node [proc, ] (sspo0019) [right=of sspo0010]{Comunicazione motivi ostativi all'accoglimento istanza (art.10bis L.241/90)};
\node [test, join] (sspo0020) {Presentazione osservazioni (10gg)};
\node [test, join] (sspo0021) {Superamento dei motivi ostativi};
%-----terza colonna----------------------------
\node [test, ] (sspo0014)[right=of sspo0011] {irregolarit\'a formali?};
\node [proc, join] (sspo0015) {Richiesta documentazione mancante};
\node [proc, join] (sspo0017) {archiviazione istanza per carenza documentazione};
\node [proc, ] (sspo0016) [right=of sspo0015]{ricevimento documentazione mancante};
%\node [proc, join] (sssc9999) {chiusura procedimento};
\node [proc, ] (sspo005B)[left=of sspo0005] {richiesta doc. integrativa (sospensione)};
\node [proc, ] (sspo0018)[left=of sspo0008] {richiesta doc. integrativa (sospensione)};
%-------------------fine posizionamento nodi-----------------------------------https://preview.overleaf.com/public/rtkznwdyqxfw/images/909eaf975d88a4b576808e04852f55af05dd11cd.jpeg
%============disegno delle linee e scrittura esito=======
\draw [->,lcnorm] (sspO0001.west) -- (ssri-cap);
%------------------------------------------
\draw[->](sspo0002.east) -| (sspo0014) node[midway,above] {SI};
%--------------------------------------------
\draw[->] (sspo0004) -| (sspo005B);
\draw[->] (sspo005B) |- (sspo0006);
\draw [*->,lcnorm] (sspo0008) -- (sspo0018);
\draw[->] (sspo0011) -- (sspo0003);
\draw[->] (sspo0020.west) |- (sssc9999);
\draw[->] (sspo0021.west) -| (sssc9999.south);
\draw[->] (sspo0021.south) -| (sspo0010.south east);
\draw[->] (sspo0009.east) -| (sspo0019);
\draw[->] (sspo0014.west) |- (sspo0017);
\draw[->] (sspo0015) -- (sspo0016);
\draw[->] (sspo0016) |- (sspo0002.north);
 \end{tikzpicture}
% =================================================
\end{document}
```

I did a test (on `sspo0002.east`), but I don't understand how it can be used for other nodes.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You should really prepare a *minimal* example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links between vertically aligned nodes are automatically drawn by `join`. I don't know how to define a label/node on a join, but you can place these labels after drawing them with a `\path` command:

```
\path (sspo0002) -- (sspo0011) node[midway,left] {SI};
```

As an example from your code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains} 
%%%<
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\begin{document}

\colorlet{lcfree}{green} 
\colorlet{lcnorm}{blue}
\colorlet{lccong}{red}

\providecommand{\cmark}[2][]{\relax} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    >=triangle 60,
    start chain=going below,
    node distance=16mm and 60mm,
    every join/.style={norm},
    ]
% positioning of nodes
\tikzset{
    norm/.style={->, draw, lcnorm},
    base/.style={draw, on chain, on grid, align=center, minimum height=4ex},
    proc/.style={base, rectangle, text width=8em},
    test/.style={base, diamond, aspect=2, text width=5em},
    it/.style={font={\small\itshape}} %questo DOVREBBE configurafre un font
}
%
\node [proc, densely dotted, it] (sspO0001) {Presentazione domanda};
\node [test, join] (sspo0002) {Domanda formalmente completa?};
\node [proc, join] (sspo0011) {Comunicazione avvio procedimento e convocazione CdS (endo > 90 gg.)};


\path (sspo0002) -- (sspo0011) node[midway,left] {SI};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or slightly shorter: `\path (sspo0002) -- node[left] {SI} (sspo0011);` ?